# How can I change the app background color without changing the action bar color in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to change the background color of my app but it changes the action bar's color and the background color to the same color. How can I have the color be separate for each.  I think it has something to do with android:background but I don't know what to change.  Here is my code

manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myfirstapptest" >


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/BarBlue"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/BarBlue"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.mycompany.myfirstapptest.MyActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="BarBlue" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Blue2</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Blue2</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/texthintcolor</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Blue2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="background">@color/primary</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#0D47A1</color>
    <color name="accent">#37474F</color>
    <color name="background">#4527A0</color>
    <color name="texthintcolor">#B39DDB</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Change the color of activity root layout with `android:background`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Using the Material theme guide](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) (which also applies to AppCompat - note the removal of the `android:` prefix which AppCompat requires) you can use just one theme (removing `BarBlue`):

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/texthintcolor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Note in this case I use `Theme.AppCompat` rather than `Theme.AppCompat.Light` as your background is quite dark (and by default the `Light` theme assumes a light background).

Comment: Thank you that worked exactly how I needed it to work

Comment: If this helped answer your question, please make sure to accept the answer